# URI structure for restful API

Tags: rest, authentication, uri

I use basic authentication, so URI looks like http://test:password@site.com/.

If I want to give all users, I create an URI like http://test:password@site.com/users/

But what address should I use if I want to give a specific user? This should be

```
http://test:password@site.com/users/test/
```

or just

```
http://test:password@site.com/test/
```

or I don't know.

The reason that I am asking this question is that this type of authorization means that URI already contains username.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are describing isn't basic authentication. Basic authentication (and by that I mean HTTP Basic authentication) uses an Authorization header to communicate an encoded username / password and keeps it out of the URL completely. Why are you inventing this scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a resource URI in a hierarchical fashion has the benefit that you won't have any id collisions. Your alternative version `http://test:password@site.com/test/` could become problematic if you add another resource type (e.g. Role) with id `test`. You will have to ensure that your IDs are unique over all resource types and not only for a specific type. In addition: It's no longer clear, whether your resource URI points to an User or a Role.

And while it is not really required for REST it's one of the naming things that makes it easier for us humans to think about a REST API: "User Resources can be found in URIs containing the "users" label seems just so normal. REST itself is actually URI agnostic so it really shouldn't matter. But if you want to use meaningful (human-readable) URIs I would say

```
GET http://test:password@site.com/users/
```

will return all users.

```
POST http://test:password@site.com/users/
```

will create a new User and a new resource with an URI.

```
PUT http://test:password@site.com/users/test
```

will change the User resource identified with this URI and to fulfil reasonable expectations you should be able to get this user resource as

```
GET http://test:password@site.com/users/test
```

Last thing to consider: the authorised user might want to access the user resource for a different user (as unlikely as this scenario might currently seem):

```
GET http://another:password@site.com/users/test
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. I have checked [Fielding's chapter on REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and the [Basic auth RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) and can't seem to find a definitive answer, but my best guess it that the authentication portion of the URI is not considered a part of resource identification. Meaning that you should pretend it is not there and use:

```
//site.com/users/test/
```

As the URI for a single user. Here is my reasoning.

1. Browser implementation - The auth portion of the URI (test:password@) is automatically hidden in my current versions of Chrome and Firefox and [Internet Explorer denies direct input outright](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489).
2. If the user:password@ portion made the resource URI unique, then every resource for every user would be unique. That just seems a little crazy overboard to me.
3. You would never, ever want to include a username and password in an external reference like this:

`<a href="https://admin:swordfish@site.com/users/">Log in as admin!</a>`

It seems to me that including authentication information in the URL is a hack that breaks statelessness and violates the first REST interface constraint ([Identification of resources](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)) but it fills and need so we sweep it under the rug and pretend that it is not really part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you have with that approach is  that a url

//user:password@site.com/test

is equivalent to

//site.com/test

when you are passing using and password as HTTP Authentication headers

Most developers I know wouldn't like to pass user/password on the URL, so they would choose the second option. Now you have an interesting problem, since you have two identical URLs pointing to exactly the same resource, which is contrary to REST, but more importantly, it's contrary to HTTP caching.

The moment your users go trough any proxy (and they can't control that, since a lot of proxies can and will be used by organisations and ISPs) you might be serving a cached version of a user to a different user. Not nice.

The user and password are NOT really a part of the URL. They are a mechanism most browsers accept for passing http basic AUTH headers, but it's not the URL, so you need to provide unique URIs for unique resources. That is the REST way, and in the case of GET request you should be worried if you don't do it.

As an aside, please please please tell me you are going to implement https for this. Passing the user and password on http is a very bad idea. And even if you use HTTPS, encouraging your users to pass the user/pass embedded in the URI means that the user and password is going to be clearly visible on every log of the system (apache/nginx, app server...). That is quite ugly. So I would recommend you to use https and discourage your users from passing AUTH data on the URL. AUTH data should be passed either as a part of a body on a POST request or as a header.